FileSystemWatcher not working when running as a Windows service in .NET 8
I have an app that works well as a cmd line app, but when running as a service, the FileSystemWatcher stops working.
I have validated that the service has access to the files as it's using the same files elsewhere in the service.
My BackgroundService is setup like this:
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private FileSystemWatcher _watcher, _watcher2;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        SetupFileSystemWatchers();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

Here is how my FileSystemWatchers are set up:
    private void SetupFileSystemWatchers()
    {
        try
        {
            _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
            {
                Path = @"\\10.10.1.10\files$\1\2\3\",
                IncludeSubdirectories = true,
                NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName
            };
            _watcher.Created += async (sender, e) =>
            {
               _logger.LogInformation("Created");
               await FileWatcherFileChanged(sender, e);
            };
            _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            _watcher2 = new FileSystemWatcher
            {
                Path = @"\\10.10.1.10\files$\1\2\4\",
                IncludeSubdirectories = true,
                NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName
            };

            _watcher2.Created += async (sender, e) =>
            {                   
               _logger.LogInformation("Created");
               await FileWatcherFileChanged(sender, e);
            };
            _watcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            _logger.LogInformation("Watchers set up successfully.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Error setting up file system watchers.");
        }
    }

    private async Task FileWatcherFileChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        await _manage.RepoChanged(e.FullPath);
    }
}

I have traces all over my code to figure what happens and it seems everything is initialized properly, but then event just does not get triggered when run as a service. Same exact code run as a console app on the same server and it works perfectly.

Is your service running in the Local System account? That's the default, but that account may not have access to your network. You should try running in a regular user account that you know has access to the network and see if your code works then.
To check/change the account, start the Services app (run services.msc) and switch to the "Log On" tab. Enter your user name and password there.

No I tried that and I have the same result. I  Run the same function to read files and modify them on a periodic timer(daily) as well as on a FileChange. On a period timer it works, I access all files, but on a File change never gets called. But exact same code as a Console App works for periodic as well as a File change.
